# JSON Multiple results instead of the first

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JavaScript to parse JSON results. Currently i have `json.results[0]` to retrive the first result.

My question is, how would i be able to return all the results at once?

Comment: Have you tried `json.results`?

Answer (score 1):

You cant, unless you're using a javascript library or plugin. The best you can do with plain javascript is iterate through the results and process each item one by one...

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++){
    console.log(json.results[i].property);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking how can you read all the results one by one ?

```
  var results = json.results;

  for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; ++i) {

    console.log(results[i]);

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to Loop trough a json**

Your question is not very specific about keys and how do you wanna display it but here is a short example with a demo based on a properly formatted immaginary json string:

```
var jsonStr='[{"key":1,"key2":"a"},{"key":2,"key2":"b"}]';
```

**JS**

```
var allResults=JSON.parse(jsonStr),html='';
for(var a=0,currentResult;currentResult=allResults[a];++a){
 html+=currentResult.key+' - '+currentResult.key2+'<br>';
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML=html;
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/U2fT6/

*If you have any questions just ask.*